# Another css vertical align

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Trying to get the grey box on the right to centre align without adding margins/padding to it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
#frame { border: 1px solid #999; padding: 0.5em; width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; }  
#header { height: 40px; line-height: 40px; background-color: #eee; position: relative; width: 100%; }
h3 { margin: 0em; padding: 0em; }
h3 span { margin-left: 0.5em; }
a { float: right; text-align: right;  }
a span {  vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ccc; width: 1em; height: 1em; color: #fff; margin-right: 0.5em; display: inline-block; }
#content { height: 16em; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="frame">
<div id="header">
<h3><span>Heading</span><a href="#"><span></span></a></h3>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hotdiggity/4yGh8/

Comment: which grey box? the small one? it is already centered to me

Comment: To center vertically in the white box? or center it in the light-gray box? - Maybe the tag is misleading..

Comment: "grey box on the right to centre align..." within the horizontal grey strap. It's only slightly off but would be interested to know if there's a way of centering it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to go about this, but none of them are perfect.

I've modified the markup slightly to make it easier to write selectors for:

```
<div id="frame">
<div id="header">
<h3><span>Heading</span><span><a href="#"></a></span></h3>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</div>
```

## CSS Tables

The result might not be pretty if you have content that's going to wrap:

http://jsfiddle.net/4yGh8/4/

```
#frame { border: 1px solid #999; padding: 0.5em; width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; }  
#header { height: 40px; line-height: 40px; background-color: #eee; position: relative; width: 100%; }
h3 { margin: 0em; padding: 0em; display: table; width: 100%; }
h3 span { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
h3 span { padding: 0 0.5em; width: 100% }
h3 span:last-child { width: 1px; line-height: 1; }
a {  background-color: #ccc; width: 1em; height: 1em; color: #fff; display: block }
#content { height: 16em; }
```

## Flexbox

Make sure you check http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox to see which prefixes you need to make this work.

http://jsfiddle.net/4yGh8/6/ (prefixes not included)

```
#frame { border: 1px solid #999; padding: 0.5em; width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; }  
#header { height: 40px; line-height: 40px; background-color: #eee; position: relative; width: 100%; }

h3 {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

h3 span {
    margin: 0 .5em;
}

h3 span:first-child {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

a {  background-color: #ccc; width: 1em; height: 1em; color: #fff; display: block }
#content { height: 16em; }
```

## Absolute Positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/4yGh8/7/

```
#frame { border: 1px solid #999; padding: 0.5em; width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; }  
#header { height: 40px; line-height: 40px; background-color: #eee; position: relative; width: 100%; }

h3 {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    position: relative;
}

h3 span {
    padding: 0 .5em;
}

h3 span:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em; /* half of the element's height */
}

a {  background-color: #ccc; width: 1em; height: 1em; color: #fff; display: block }
#content { height: 16em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can do.

1. add another box en limit is in width until your block is in the middle with float right
2. use margin & padding

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `position:relative` to your `#frame` and then `position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0; margin:auto;` to yout `#header`. I edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yGh8/3/)